Android interface crashes when bluetooth is off and trying to access it
I have a phone with MIUI version 13.0.8. When I try to open an app that uses bluetooth but it is not on, the whole interface of the phone restarts giving the following exceptions. Is this a Xiaomi error or it is the app's fault?
*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: android.fg
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED dat=package:com.stt.android.suunto flg=0x45000010 (has extras) } in com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService$3@92d1c39
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1708)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback)' on a null object reference
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService.restartBleScan(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:1451)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService.updateSpecialAccessPermissionAsSystem(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:847)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService.$r8$lambda$3n3hT9_T4IzBqXOYPVsPevhYbMY(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.accept(Unknown Source:6)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.doInvoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:295)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.PooledLambdaImpl.invoke(PooledLambdaImpl.java:204)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.run(OmniFunction.java:97)
    at com.android.internal.util.function.pooled.OmniFunction.runOrThrow(OmniFunction.java:232)
    at android.os.Binder.withCleanCallingIdentity(Binder.java:393)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService.updateSpecialAccessPermissionForAssociatedPackage(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:812)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService.access$700(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:155)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService$3.lambda$onPackageModified$2$CompanionDeviceManagerService$3(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:284)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService$3$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.acceptOrThrow(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.android.internal.util.CollectionUtils.forEach(CollectionUtils.java:425)
    at com.android.server.companion.CompanionDeviceManagerService$3.onPackageModified(CompanionDeviceManagerService.java:283)
    at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.onReceive(PackageMonitor.java:406)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1694)

